# jQuery filtering nth-child(n + x) not returning expected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

Given the following markup:

```
<dl>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="first">We are open 24/7.</dd>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="second">We are open 24/7.</dd>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="third">We are open 24/7.</dd>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="fourth">We are open 24/7.</dd>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="fifth">We are open 24/7.</dd>
</dl>

console.log($('dd').get());  
//returns - [dd.first, dd.second, dd.third, dd.fourth, dd.fifth]
```

Using this selector to add a class of 'hide' `$('dd').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').addClass('hide');` applies the class to the second,third,fourth and fifth. Should it not apply the class to the fourth and fifth? It's as if the $('dd') selector has included dt elements in the count. why is this so?

```
<dl>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="first">We are open 24/7.</dd>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="second hide">We are open 24/7.</dd>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="third hide">We are open 24/7.</dd>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="fourth hide">We are open 24/7.</dd>
    <dt>What are your hours?</dt>
    <dd class="fifth hide">We are open 24/7.</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nth-selector will search only for the child count, other filter are not applied to it - your selector will fetch all `dd` elements whose index of greater than 3

You can try slice() though

```
$('dd').slice(3).addClass('hide');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CfH4d/)

Comment: So to paraphrase - nth child counts all elements from the parent, which will include the dt indexes as well. ?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('dd').slice(3).addClass('hide');
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fm345/